# android cannot access thread class

Tags: java, android, web-services

//when i debug this code the compiler do not compiles ContactList.java so loop goes to infinite state

//   Contact.java class

```
rslt = "START";

            ContactList.userid=getIntent().getStringExtra("userID").toString();

            ContactList con = new ContactList();

            con.join();
            con.start();
            //here control do not go to ContactList.java 
            Log.i("JSONObject", rslt);
            while (rslt == "START") {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured Login Again..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

where my ContactList.java is:

```
public class ContactList extends Thread {

    public WebServices cs;
      public static String userid;


        public void run(){
            try{
                cs=new WebServices();
                String resp=cs.contactlistcall(userid);  **\\webservice method**
                Contact.rslt = resp;


            }catch(Exception ex)
            {

                Contact.rslt=ex.toString();
            }    
        }

}
```

//this resp is came from my sql server database through .net webservice

Comment: `while (rslt == "START")` should be `while (rslt .equals("START"))`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thank you but no effect still same problem.

Comment: I think try it as `while (rslt .equals(Contact.rslt))` ??  or `Contact.rslt=rslt;while (Contact.rslt .equals("START"))`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K, it's better to write it 'while("START".equals(rslt))' to protect against NPE

Answer (score -1):

Be warning with String comparation, because String is an Object not a primitive type :

```
while (rslt == "START")
```

Should be

```
while (rslt.equals("START"))
```

**EDIT**

Contact.java

```
while (con.getRslt().equals("START"))
```

Comment: All right, let me see... rest String is never changed in Contact.java ?

Comment: no. and in another class i used this class(ContactList.java) it works properly

Comment: Yes, but if you never change this String, code will always loop... You should maybe use a String from ContactList.java, using a getter (see my edit)